# Set-Cookie in response header is not saved into browser cookie storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

the response header is

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, x-request, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:private
Connection:close
Content-Length:100
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 14 Feb 2017 02:45:56 GMT
Server:nginx/1.2.8
Set-Cookie:USER=6ae633831f39447688892e6b2b156cec; Max-Age=604800; Path=/
Set-Cookie:USERINFO=298967; Max-Age=604800; Path=/
X-Powered-By:node.js
X-Ua-Compatible:chrome=1
```

the cookie format's right (used cookie package to serialize ). the server is developed by node.js.

not only chrome, Firefox doesn't work too. the document.cookie is empty and also i can't see cookie in application section of chrome developer tool.

Any wrong in response header ?? Please help .

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur due to multiple responses from server to client.

For example if you are sending a response to the server using `response.send()` and same time using 
you are using `response.setHeader()`

This problem can be solve by creating cookie in client side using javascript.
And reading its value from node.js

Answer (score 0):

The answer is because i used fetch() API that have to pass {credentials => 'same-origin'} option.